# While creating the elastic synthetic monitoring via docker run unable to view monitoring details in Kibana dashboard, getting error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, terraform

Errors While creating the elastic synthetic monitoring via docker run unable to view monitoring details in Kibana dashboard. Getting the below errors while run the docker run command. So please help me solve this issues.

facing the below two errors while executing the synthetic monitoring via docker run.
Error 1: -
2021-05-07T09:14:14.920Z ERROR synthexec/synthexec.go:172 Error waiting for command /tmp/elastic-synthetics-068278346/node_modules/.bin/elastic-synthetics . --screenshots --json --network --outfd 3: exit status 1

Error 2: -
2021-05-07T09:14:14.921Z WARN synthexec/synthexec.go:183 Error executing command '/tmp/elastic-synthetics-068278346/node_modules/.bin/elastic-synthetics . --screenshots --json --network --outfd 3': exit status 1

Below are the files we are using to create new synthetic teste monitoring purpose:

File 1: one.journey.ts

```
import { journey, step } from '@elastic/synthetics';
import { deepStrictEqual } from 'assert';
import { join } from 'path';

journey("check if thegeneral is present", async ({page}) => {
step("Go to general home page", async () => {
await page.goto('http://www.thegeneral.com/legal/personal-information');
})
});
```

File 2: two.journey.ts

```
import { journey, step } from '@elastic/synthetics';
import { deepStrictEqual } from 'assert';
import { join } from 'path';

journey("check elastic home pag is present", async ({page}) => {
step("Go to elastic.co", async () => {
await page.goto('https://www.elastic.co');
})
});
```

======docker run cmd sample=======================

```
  sudo docker run \
  --rm \
  --name=heartbeat \
  --user=heartbeat \
  --volume="$PWD/heartbeat.yml:/usr/share/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml:ro" \
  --volume="$PWD:/two.journey.ts:ro" \
  --volume="$PWD:/one.journey.ts:ro" \
  docker.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat:7.12.0 heartbeat -e \
  -E cloud.id= \
  -E cloud.auth=
```